# Laravel: Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::claims does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to install [a Laravel package](https://github.com/exatech-group/Laravel-H5P) to create an editor for H5P contents (e-learning modules based on JavaScript). There's not much documentation for the package. It's `composer.json` requires Laravel 5.8, so I started with a fresh Laravel 5.8.35 app, ran `php artisan make:auth` and installed the package.

Now I need to open the page `/library`, but I get an error:

```
BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::claims does not exist.
```

This error is caused by `/vendor/exatech-group/laravel-h5p/src/LaravelH5p/LaravelH5p.php`, which contains several calls to a `claims()` method:

```
$settings = [
  'baseUrl'            => config('laravel-h5p.domain'),
  'url'                => config('laravel-h5p.domain').'/api/h5p_protect?'.(Auth::check() ? 'token='.auth()->claims(['referer' => app('Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator')->previous()])->tokenById(Auth::id()).'&' : '').'data=',
  'postUserStatistics' => (config('laravel-h5p.h5p_track_user', true) === '1') && Auth::check(),
  'ajax'               => [
    'setFinished'     => route('h5p.ajax.finish').(Auth::check() ? '?token='.auth()->claims(['referer' => app('Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator')->previous()])->tokenById(Auth::id()) : ''),
    'contentUserData' => route('h5p.ajax.content-user-data').'?content_id=:contentId&data_type=:dataType&sub_content_id=:subContentId'.(Auth::check() ? '&token='.auth()->claims(['referer' => app('Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator')->previous()])->tokenById(Auth::id()) : ''),
  ],
  // a few more elements
]
```

I can't find any info on this method. How is this supposed to work, is there a specific Laravel version that contains it or is there anything I missed to install?

Comment: That may be due to the version mismatch

Comment: What version are you on?

Comment: Which version mismatch do you mean? I installed the package inside an empty Laravel 5.8.35 app.

Comment: I meant that you should use the same Laravel Package which you are already on

Comment: The `SessionGuard` does not contain any such method so maybe any other implementation is causing the error. Also, the guy has forked a repo but not allowing to create any issue.

Comment: Yes, for the moment I used the code from [the source repo](https://github.com/djoudi/Laravel-H5P) for the `$settings` array instead.